# Why I am getting {"readyState":0,"status":0,"statusText":"NetworkError: A network error occurred."}

Tags: javascript, html

I'm still a newbie and trying to learn web development, hoping for somebody that can help. Thanks!

I am using Firefox/Chrome and I'm getting error

> {"readyState":0,"status":0,"statusText":"NetworkError: A network error occurred."}

when the server will take a long time to respond with my ajax post request below due to querying large data from my database (querying 1 year of data).

```js
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  data: JSON.stringify(data),
  contentType: 'application/json',
  url: 'http://xx.xxx.xx.xx:3000/postFilter',
  crossDomain: true,
  async: false,
  timeout: 0,
  success: function(data) {
    alert(data);
  },
  error: function(error) {
    alert(JSON.stringify(error));
  }
})
```

Note: This error will not occur if the server responds quickly, querying only small data (querying only 1 month of data).

Comment: This has nothing to do with your client-side code, the request is simply timing out. Find out what slows down your server-side queries and fix it. If there's too much data returned, consider pagination

Comment: FYI, the `error` callback accepts three parameters ~ `(jqXHR jqXHR, String textStatus, String errorThrown)`. Logging only the first isn't particularly useful

Comment: the problem is with your server the you should increase the timeout of server responding

Comment: Thank you all for your comments and suggestions. It somehow shed light to what I'm going to do to resolve this issue.